# Get the result of remote script in Expect

Tags: expect

Im executing the remote script and checking return status of the script but if I do in the following way its returning the status of the password but not the status of the called script.How can I get the return status of the called script. Please help thanks in advance.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
proc auto { } {
global argv
set timeout 120
set ip XXXX.XXX.XX.XX
set user name
set password pass
set ssh_opts {-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no}
set script /path-to-script/test.sh
spawn ssh {*}$ssh_opts $user@$ip bash $script {*}$argv
expect "Password:"
send "$password\r"
send "echo $?\r"
expect {
  "0\r" { puts "Test passed."; }
  timeout { puts "Test failed."; }
}
expect eof
}
auto {*}$argv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're automating `ssh bash remote_script`, so you're not going to get a shell prompt where you can `echo $?` -- ssh will launch your script and then exit.

What you need to do is get the exit status of the spawned process (ssh is supposed to exit with the remote command's exit status). expect's `wait` command gets you the exit status (among other info)

```tcl
spawn ssh {*}$ssh_opts $user@$ip bash $script {*}$argv
expect {
    "Password:" { send "$password\r"; exp_continue }
    timeout     { puts "Test failed." }
    eof
}

# ssh command is now finished
exp_close
set info [wait]
# [lindex $info 0] is the PID of the ssh process
# [lindex $info 1] is the spawn id
# [lindex $info 2] is the success/failure indicator
if {[lindex $info 2] == 0} {
    puts "exit status = [lindex $info 3]"
} else {
    puts "error code = [lindex $info 3]"
}
```